# Java extract only first letters/characters from String

Tags: java, regex, string

Hello guys I want to extract only first letters from this String:

```
  String str = "使 徒 行 傳 16:31 ERV-ZH";
```

I only want to get these characters:

```
  使 徒 行 傳
```

and not include

```
   ERV-ZH
```

Only the letters or characters before the numbers plus the colon.

Note that Chinese letters can also be English and other letters.

this is what I've tried:

```
str.split(" ")[0];
```

But I'm only getting the first letter. Do you have an idea how to achieve my requirement? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**NOTE:**

Also, strings are dynamic so I only presented sample characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex `^([\\D\\s]+)`, this is what you need:

```
  String str = "使 徒 行 傳 16:31 ERV-ZH";
  String pattern = "^([\\D\\s]+)";

  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
  } else {
     System.out.println("NO MATCH");
  }
}
```

This is a **[live DEMO](https://ideone.com/9uEbrt)** here.

In the following regex `^([\\D\\s]+)`:

- `^` will match only in the begginnig.
- `\\D` will avoid matching any number.

**Note** that this will be the case for any string.

Comment: it's getting ERV-ZH when I tried to change str = "H E L L O 16:31 ERV-ZH"

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes No it's not !  it just matches H E L L O, you can test it in the DEMO.

Comment: Okay sure will test it

Comment: What if characters are in Arabic?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes It will be working too, this is a [DEMO](https://ideone.com/9nhYKi).

Comment: Even arabic is in RTL?

Comment: yes of course you can test it there, it works because it's a regex and works dynamically with all strings. Indeed it's very powerful, and not like split() wich will not work in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the desired output

```
String str = "使 徒 行 傳 16:31 ERV-ZH";

String[] test = str.split("\\d\\d:\\d\\d");

for (String s : test) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The first element will be the part before the time and so on

Edit: if you are in need to be more dynamic for times like `6:31` or `16:6` then you could use this regex `"\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}"`

Comment: It's still getting ERV-ZH

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes yeah, because it does split, you could just continue with the element 0 in the array.

Comment: I added to Stringbuilder, how do I remove ERV-ZH ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't always have a *date pattern* that can be used as a delimiter in the middle, and are looking for a more generic solution, you could go with this: `str.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s]+.*", "")`